# How to extract (read and delete) a line from file with a single command?

Tags: bash, sed

I would like to extract the first line from a file, read into a variable and delete right afterwards, with a single command. I know `sed` can read the first line as follows:

```
sed '1q' file.txt
```

or delete it as follows:

```
sed '1q;d' file.txt
```

but can I somehow do both with a single command?
The reason for this is that multiple processes will be reading the first line of the file, and I want to minimize the chances of them getting the same line.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and add sample input and expected output. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: For concurrency you need better mechanisms that this!!

Comment: What more do you want me to show? What I tried is to use these two commands, but what I want is the result with a single access to the file. The expected output of the two commands I showed is obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### It's impossible.

Except you read the manpage, and have Gnu-sed:

```
echo -e {1..3}"\n" > input
cat input
1
 2
 3

sed -n '1p;2,$ Woutput' input 
1
cat output 
 2
 3
```

Explanation:

```
 sed -n '1p;2,$ Woutput' input
```

- -n no output by default
- 1p; print line 1
- 2,$ from line 2 until $ last line

  - W (non posix) Write buffer to file

From the man page gnu sed:

```
   w filename
          Write the current pattern space to filename.

   W filename
          Write the first line of the current pattern space to filename.  This is a GNU extension.
```

However, reading and experimenting takes longer, than opening the file in a full blown office suite and deleting the line by hand, or invoking a text-to-speech framework and training it, to do the job.

It doesn't work if invoked in posix style:

```
sed -n --posix '1p;2,$ Woutput' input
```

And you still have the hard hanwork of renaming output to input again.

I didn't try to write to input in place, because that could damage my carefully crafted input file - try it on own risk:

```
sed -n '1p;2,$ Winput' input
```

However, you might set up a filesystem notify job, which always rename freshly created output files to input again. But I fear you can't do it from within the sed command. Except ... *(to be continued)*

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?

```
$ cat input | sed 1q && sed -i '1d' input
```

For example:

```
$ echo -e {1..3}"\n" > input
$ cat input
1
 2
 3
$ cat input | sed 1q && sed -i '1d' input
1
$ cat input
 2
 3
```

Actually it is the same as below. Does it help on the concurrence problem?

```
sed 1q input && sed -i '1d' input
```